# Prevent toggle occuring before droppable animation finishes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-droppable

## What I have:

Using jQuery UI, I'm dragging/dropping a div from one div to another.

The dropping event triggers:

1. An animation that eases/snaps the dropped div into place.
2. The toggling (show/hide) of yet another div.

## The problem:

The toggling occurs before the animation is complete. I need the toggling to occur **AFTER** the animation completes.

## Live example + code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dominornovus/3Hq3q/2/

## What I've tried:

I've unsuccessfully attempted use of an animated selector:

```
$(":animated").promise().done(function() {
//code here
}
```

## My question:

How do I prevent the toggle occurring before the droppable animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback in `animate()` :

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var drop_p = $(this).offset();
        var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
        var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left + 1;
        var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top + 1;
        ui.draggable.animate({
            top: '+=' + top_end,
            left: '+=' + left_end
        }, function() {  //callback
            $(".somediv").toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hq3q/3/)

Comment: Much thanks for the working code (and +1 for the 2 minute response time). Following your instruction, I've read up on animation callbacks (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Most convenient.

Comment: Yes, the callbacks are invaluable when animating stuff, no need for complicated functions or promises. You're welcome!